# Accessing files in Android

Tags: java, android, filesystems

Is there a way in Android to access a file simply by its filename and path?

I am trying to move some code into Android from a normal Java project, where I have .wav files stored in a subdirectory of \src (bad practice?).  Android cannot access these with the same relative filepath clearly.

Is there a filepath for these files in the Android file system or is it simply not possible to do this?

I've read a few things about the Assets folder so am aware of the fact that you can use this to copy files across into the app location, but it would seem a lot of code to change for what I assumed would not be a big issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I m not sure if the files in \src folder is shipped with apk in the first place.. it has to be asset folder

Comment: Have a look at this - it appears to be what you need...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210239/how-to-use-relative-path-instead-of-absolute-path

Comment: I don't think it works even it is compile-able. As asset is the only place where you can keep raw files with folder structure. (Another place would be Res\raw which has no folder structure.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ship your files with your application then there is no other option then placing your files in the **assets** folder. You can access them by their url:

file:///android_asset/your_file.wav

which is useful in web pages. You can have for instance some CSS stored in assets folder and reference it as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/your.css" />
```

If you want to access files in the Java code, then there are two options.

- to obtain [AssetFileDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html) by the mentioned url and open InputStream for your file
- to open InputStream for your file via [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) by its file name

No other project folder is packed into the .apk file, except the **libs** folder which is supposed to distribute libraries, and **res** folder which is to store resources accesible only via resource methods/loaders. Content files must be in **assets** folder.

Comment: OK thanks @vitakot, one quick point though - for the path android_asset, is this always these two words or is there any link to the package or app name in question?  e.g. File example = new File("android_asset/example.wav");

Answer (score 1):

for me, I put it in the res/raw folder

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music.wav);
    if (afd != null) {
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
    }
```