# How do I change the directory a PrintWriter saves to in Java?

Tags: java

My program takes in user input, and puts it into a `PrintWriter`.

I am unsure of how to change the directory that the `PrintWriter` saves the text file to. I also need the name of the files to dynamically change based on user input. Here is the code for the `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
        "ChangeLog" + textField.getText() + textField_1.getText() + textField_9.getText() + ".txt",
        "UTF-8");
writer.println("Version Number: " + version);
writer.println("Start Date: " + textField.getText());
writer.println("Start time: " + textField_1.getText());
if (rdbtnYes.isSelected()) {
    writer.println("Change was documented in the IT info sheet.");
}
if (rdbtnNo.isSelected()) {
    writer.println("Change was NOT documented in the IT info sheet.");
}
writer.println("Budget Implecation(S): " + textField_2.getText());
writer.println("Server/Network Device: " + textField_3.getText());
writer.println("Process Of Changes Made: " + textField_4.getText());
writer.println("Need(s)/Reason(s) for Change: " + textField_5.getText());
writer.println("Issues/Problems: " + textField_6.getText());
writer.println("Outcome/Results: " + textField_7.getText());
writer.println("Notes/Comments/Other Info" + textField_8.getText());
writer.close();
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496700/how-to-use-printwriter-and-file-classes-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String)) you are using takes a String argument - denoting a file name.

File names can be just that; or they can **include** path information. You want a different path - then change the filename to include that path!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496700/how-to-use-printwriter-and-file-classes-in-java) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210239/how-to-use-relative-path-instead-of-absolute-path) for relative vs. absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is that you will need to create a FileWriter object and tell it what location will the file sit where you want to write stuff. Then you'll pass your FileWriter object as an argument to the PrintWriter constructor.
See the example below:

```
FileWriter  writer      = new FileWriter("d:\\path_to_directory\\report.txt");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter (writer);
```

Hope this helps! :)